# Wicket - Trouble with submit button function when value is null

Tags: java, html, wicket

This is my `yesNoPanel` class, extending `Panel` :

```
public class YesNoPanel extends Panel {

/**
 * 
 */

private String password = "Password";
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}



private static final long serialVersionUID = -8356163236155431543L;

public String getPw()
  {
         String pw=ConfigurationHelper.getConfigurationProperty("REFRESH_CACHE_PASSWORD", "");
         return pw;
  }

public YesNoPanel(String id, String message, final ModalWindow modalWindow, final ConfirmationAnswer answer) {
    super(id);

    final Form yesNoForm = new Form("yesNoForm");
    final String wrongPw = "Wrong Password";


    final TextField<String> passwordString = new RequiredTextField<String>("password", new PropertyModel(this, password));

    passwordString.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") { 
        @Override 
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        }
    });


    MultiLineLabel messageLabel = new MultiLineLabel("message", message);
    yesNoForm.add(messageLabel);
    final Label wrongPW = new Label("WrongPassword", wrongPw );
    modalWindow.setTitle("Please confirm");
    modalWindow.setInitialHeight(200);
    modalWindow.setInitialWidth(350);


    AjaxButton yesButton = new AjaxButton("yesButton", yesNoForm) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3827487963204274386L;
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {
            if (target != null && password.equals(getPw())) {
                answer.setAnswer(true);
                modalWindow.close(target);
            }else if(target != null && !password.equals(getPw())){
                answer.setAnswer(false);
                wrongPW.setVisible(true);
                target.add(wrongPW);
            }
        }
    };

    AjaxButton noButton = new AjaxButton("noButton", yesNoForm) {
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {
            if (target != null) {
                answer.setAnswer(false);
                modalWindow.close(target);
                wrongPW.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    };

    yesNoForm.add(yesButton);
    yesNoForm.add(noButton);
    yesNoForm.add(passwordString);
    add(yesNoForm);
    wrongPW.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
    wrongPW.setVisible(false);
    add(wrongPW);

  }

}
```

and the HTML in question :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:wicket>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <wicket:panel>
        <form wicket:id="yesNoForm" action="">
            <span wicket:id="message">Are you sure?</span>
            <table style="width: 65%;" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <input type="submit" wicket:id="noButton" value="No" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <input type="text" wicket:id="password" size = "20" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <input type="submit" wicket:id="yesButton" value="Yes" />
                    </td> 
                </tr>
            </table>

        </form>
       <font color="red"><p align="center" wicket:id="WrongPassword"></p> </font>
    </wicket:panel>
</body>
```

As it is now, when the user opens the modal window the input box is filled with the wicket id `password` - which is simply the string "Password".  The `Yes` or `No` buttons don't do anything if the input if left blank (or a placeholder is used, which is preferable).  Why is this and how can I work around it?

Comment: Use debuger, set breakpoint, look at variables, step code ...

Comment: Ahh I know, been trying to fix weblogic local debugging in eclipse all day - this is part of the issue :( I've had 2 senior engineers pour over it for a couple of hours with me, to no avail.

Comment: I don't understand - what is the problem? I've copied your code , created test page - it works. I've just changed `private String password = "Password";` to `private IModel<String> password = new Model<>("Password");`  and changed `ConfirmationAnswer` to `IModel<Boolean>`. Perhaps you need to check this code ? -> `String pw=ConfigurationHelper.getConfigurationProperty("REFRESH_CACHE_PASSWORD", "");`. Debug the value of `pw` from configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a TextField rather than a RequiredTextField.
Using a RequiredTextField with blank input, the buttons don't do anything.

Comment: Ah seems logical thanks for your help.  I'll give this a go tomorrow :)

Comment: And override `AjaxButton#onError()` if you use Wicket validation, like `RequiredTextField`.

Comment: Going to have to retract that unfortunately, when using only `TextField` and not `RequiredTextField` I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.  When I override `onError()` both buttons default to `onError`.

Comment: Maybe NPE has occurred in the equals methods.
null check for "target" is not necessary.
You should do null check for "password" instead.

Comment: @rysh , thanks for the input.  I changed my `if` conditional to `password.equals(getPw())`  and my `else-if` to `password.equals(null) || !password.equals(getPw())` and it works, until I check for a `null` value in which case I get the `java.lang.NullPointerException`.  Cannot figure out why

Comment: tried setting `passwordString.setConvertEmptyInputStringToNull(false)` and checking for an empty string, but still the same error..

Comment: figured it out - instead of checking the value of `password` I should have been checking the value of `passwordString` - along with changing `RequiredTextField` to `TextField` this solved my issues.